# Convert UUID from type string to integer Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string, uuid

So I am trying to pass a UUID to a function which then calls and endpoint of deleting a blog. I'm getting the id but it is in string format like "9ba354d1-2d4c-4265-aee1-54877f22312e" and i get an error of `TypeError: Cannot create property 'message' on string '9ba354d1-2d4c-4265-aee1-54877f22312e'`
I tried using the parseInt() but it's not working in my case. Any solution ?

Comment: Neither integers nor strings can have a property "message" set on them in JavaScript (at least one they won't all share), and UUID is typically either a string or a byte buffer, not an integer. It is very hard to figure out what you are trying to do without a better description, or even better, some code as well.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to convert string to number. all members inside the string should be number. You can't convert to integer, because there are non number characters inside the string. if you are using this for giving unique ids, then you can use timestamp.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).